# Cannot get folder under inbox

Tags: python-3.x, outlook

I have followed the recommended process but it just, fails to get the folder.

```
inbox = win32com.client.gencache.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

sj = inbox.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders["todo"]
sjDone = inbox.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders["Done"]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "fails"? Do you get an error? What is it? Or just null back? BTW, the variable named inbox points to the Namespace object, not a MAPIFolder object.

Comment: Sorry new to stack over flow, anyway the below answer helped me.  Something to do with Dispatch not being an attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I have had a similar issue a few months ago, and found that using the below line should fix your code.

```
inbox = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
```